# Why margin is included in my standard box model?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="article">
            <h2>Article</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="blog">
            <h2>Blog</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this css

```
.container {
    width: 1200px;
}
.article {
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
}

.blog {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
}
```

now they are perfecly putted inside the `parent` because 2 x 600px = 1200px ( the parent's width ).

But if i put margin in `blog`

```
.blog {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

then the layout is broken.

On the mozilla documentation is mentioned that

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model#the_standard_css_box_model

standard box model does not include the margin it self.
So only padding and border. But i give not padding and border rto my `blog div` i give only margin and i expect the layout to not be broken and to have still actuil width of 600px.

Can somoene explain me what is happening here and why my layout is broken

Comment: _The margin is not counted towards the actual size of the box — but it affects the total space that the box will take up on the page,_ so your blog class takes 600px plus 40 px of margin

Comment: IMO, the MDN explanation is garbled. The _box_ **always** includes the margin. It's the _box-sizing_ that **never** includes the margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is worth noting that `margin` will apply outside the borders of the element and `padding` will apply inside the element.
To understand this better consider the following examples.

**Margin**

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.parent {width: 200px; height: 220px; background: limegreen;}
.child {height: 200px; width: 100%; background: red; margin: 20px;}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see that the child element is parted way from its parent's initial position and creating a space around it.

**Padding**

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
.parent1 {width: 200px; height: 220px; background: limegreen;}
.child1 {height: 200px; width: 100%; background: red; padding: 20px;}
```

```html
<div class="parent1">
  <div class="child1">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Here the padding is applied inside the child element so it won't leave the parent's width